# Catch Error In informix

Tags: linux, informix

This program is using Informix 4GL. The purpose is to delete the report. Well actually it works well, but the problem is that only a specific user can delete the physical file of the report, which means the admin. Other user can delete the report in database but not the physical path. So I need to catch the error in syntax command `rm -f`. I tried to use WHENEVER ERROR but it couldn't catch it. Does anyone know how to do it? This is the code for deleting the report:

```
 DELETE FROM sysrpt   
 WHERE srpt_seq_no   = p_sysrpt.srpt_seq_no        
 LET sel_rpt_id = ""    
 LET sel_rpt_id = p_sysrpt.srpt_pgm_id CLIPPED, ".", 
                  p_sysrpt.srpt_seq_no USING "<<<<<<"  
 LET sel_rpt_id = sel_rpt_id CLIPPED      
 LET prt_comand = "\\rm -f ", rpt_path CLIPPED, sel_rpt_id CLIPPED
 LET prt_comand = prt_comand CLIPPED                              
 RUN prt_comand
```

Comment: The language under discussion is Informix-4GL or I4GL (or, in too many circles, just 4GL, but that always seems so presumptuous).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to capture the full error message unless you redirect stdout/stderr to another file as part of the rm command.  You can get the return code from the shell command back into the 4gl program by using the RETURNING clause of the RUN statement, e.g. you could add the following after "RUN prt_command":

```
RUN prt_comand RETURNING p_return_code
```

From memory, I believe you need to MOD 256 the return code.

Comment: Using MOD 256 would give you the signal number that the child process died of, if it in fact died from a signal.  You would divide by 256 to get the exit status.  The number returned is a 16-bit value as from the `wait()` system call.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341), where the real issue is the access permissions of the report as originally generated.

Perhaps the report file should be `chmod`-ed after generation to allow others to delete it, or the app users should have a correctly set `umask`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `rm -f` returns success even when it fails to remove the file, or the file does not exist.  If you want `rm` to return an error, you must not tell it not to return an error.

Otherwise, the advice to use:

```
RUN prt_command RETURNING p_retcode
```

is correct.  If the value of `p_retcode` is not zero, the command failed in some way.

---

The line copied below is superfluous:

```
LET prt_comand = prt_comand CLIPPED
```

If `prt_command` is a CHAR variable, then the stored result is blank-padded again (all CHAR variables are stored blank-padded to full length).  If `prt_command` is a VARCHR variable, the previous assignment with CLIPPED already removed trailing blanks.

It is not clear to me why you are using a backslash before the `rm` command.  Are you avoiding aliases?  If so, time to get rid of the alias for `rm`; it is lethal in the long term.  Learn to use the raw command correctly.  If you ever get to a machine without the alias, you won't be protected and you will misuse the command without whatever safety net the alias purports to provide.